# How do I use MySQL to take data from one table row, and copy it to the other rows with the same item number

Tags: mysql

Thanks in advance for your help! I have a table called ItemStoreDisplayName that looks like this:

```
IsParentItem   Size BaseItemID  ConfirmationStoreDisplayName
yes                 10045       Los Angeles Dodgers Authentic Home Jersey
               S    10045       
               M    10045       
               L    10045       
               XL   10045       
yes                 77245       San Francisco Giants 5950 Game Cap
               S    77245       
               M    77245       
               L    77245       
               XL   77245
```

...etc

What I need to do is take the ConfirmationStoreDisplayName from the item where "IsParentItem='yes', and copy that data into the other rows with a matching BaseItemID. So when the update is done, I want it to look like this:

```
IsParentItem   Size BaseItemID  ConfirmationStoreDisplayName
yes                 10045       Los Angeles Dodgers Authentic Home Jersey
               S    10045       Los Angeles Dodgers Authentic Home Jersey
               M    10045       Los Angeles Dodgers Authentic Home Jersey
               L    10045       Los Angeles Dodgers Authentic Home Jersey
               XL   10045       Los Angeles Dodgers Authentic Home Jersey
yes                 77245       San Francisco Giants 5950 Game Cap
               S    77245       San Francisco Giants 5950 Game Cap
               M    77245       San Francisco Giants 5950 Game Cap
               L    77245       San Francisco Giants 5950 Game Cap
               XL   77245       San Francisco Giants 5950 Game Cap
```

I realize this is terrible table structure for a database, but this is a one time update, which I will be importing into different system via csv import, that needs this data this way. If I need to separate the "Parent" items from the child items and work with 2 separate tables in order to make this happen, I can do that.

I tried this:

```
 UPDATE
 ItemStoreDisplayName AS Child
 CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT DISTINCT 
    BaseItemID, ConfirmationStoreDisplayName, IsParentItem 
  FROM 
    ItemStoreDisplayName
  WHERE 
    IsParentItem='yes'
) AS Parent
USING (BaseItemID)
SET
  Child.ConfirmationStoreDisplayName = Parent.ConfirmationStoreDisplayName
```

... but I am getting this error:
Error : Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)
Kathy

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your SQL code and it works just perfect, so the error you're getting is due to some internal weirdness (there are a number of possible reasons of why this is happening but I try to avoid technicalities). So let's see some possible solutions to your error:

- a possible fix would be to simply **restart your MySQL server**;
- if the table you're talking about contains a huge amount of data, go to your */etc/my.cnf* **configuration file** and find the lines that contain:

  *innodb_lock_wait_timeout = ...

  net_read_timeout = ...

  net_write_timeout = ...

  table_lock_wait_timeout = ...*

Uncomment these, then raise their values (to like 300 or so), and finally restart your MySQL server; if you're wondering why you should uncomment all of these, well, it seems that only one of them will do the trick, but you can't know which one because it depends on the server configuration.

- the last solution (maybe a little radical) would be to **drop your table to a backup file, restart MySQL server, and then restore it** from that backup.

Comment: Thanks Woofy! I tried restarting my MySQL server, and that did not do the trick. I am trying to locate the my.cnf file you mentioned. I am searching for it on my computer, and it says no results found. Do you know where I would look for this. I am on a mac, and I installed MySQL on my Mac using the .dmg installer ... I did not use the tar files. Could that maybe be why I can't find it?

Answer (score 0):

Cross Joins can create timeouts.

I would create a temp lookup table based on....

```
SELECT BASEITEMID, DESC FROM INVENTORY WHERE DESC != ""
```

Then Create an update statement that has a subquery in the SET clause that will fill in the missing info.

Comment: Thanks for this info Len. I was able to get the original query to run, even though it had to keep trying repeatedly due to timeouts and the connection being lost because of the number of records. I just had to do another update similar to this though, and I tried your suggestion, and that worked a little smoother with so much data :) Thanks everyone for your help!